# How to fix this message ?Severity: Notice --> Undefined property: stdClass::

Tags: mysql, angularjs, codeigniter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSGh7.png)I am trying to display table from mysql db using codeigniter and angularjs what am i doing wrong?
This is my view: list_show_data.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>List Show Data</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="decontroller">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Role</th>
<th>Privileges</th>
<th>User Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="n in list_data">
    <td>{{n.First Name}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Last Name}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Email}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Role}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Privileges}}</td>
    <td>{{n.User Name}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" href="/public/js/angular.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('decontroller', function($scope,$http){
    $scope.list_data=[];
    $http.get("ajax_load_data").success(function(result){
        $scope.list_data=result;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This my controller:MainTest.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MainTest extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function list_show_data()
{

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('list_show_data');

}

public function ajax_load_data()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $res = $this->db->get('stlc_users')->result();
    $data_arr = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($res as $r)
    {
        $data_arr[$i]['First Name'] = $r->First  ;
        $data_arr[$i]['Last Name'] = $r->Last  ;
        $data_arr[$i]['Email'] = $r->Email;
        $data_arr[$i]['Role'] = $r->Role;
        $data_arr[$i]['Privileges'] = $r->Privileges;
        $data_arr[$i]['User Name'] = $r->User  ;
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($data_arr);
}
```

}

This is the error i'm getting:

```
Severity: Notice --> Undefined property: stdClass::$First C:\xampp\htdocs\stlc\application\controllers\MainTest.php 38
ERROR - 2016-09-22 16:31:19 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined property: stdClass::$Last C:\xampp\htdocs\stlc\application\controllers\MainTest.php 39
ERROR - 2016-09-22 16:31:19 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined property: stdClass::$User C:\xampp\htdocs\stlc\application\controllers\MainTest.php 43
```

Comment: Check your stlc_users table, you probably have the columns wrong. `var_dump($r)` can also help

Comment: obviously this: `$data_arr[$i]['First Name'] = $r->First`. done any basic debugging, like checking what's in `$r`?

Comment: @MarcB, `$r` is the current value as provided by `foreach($res as $r)`

Comment: yes, but you need to check what's in it. Obviously, as per your error message, it DOESN'T have a `Friend` parameter. If your DB table name is literally `First Name`, then that space will not survive the db retrieve intact. it'll probably become `First_Name` or something.

Answer (score 2):

This error message means that the `$r` object, which represents a row from your DB table `stlc_users`, does not have these two properties: `Last` and `User`. Most probably the reason for this is that there are no columns with these names in your DB table.

Comment: i added image link, it seems i have it set. I am a newbie as you can obviously tell.

Comment: Your column names are "First_Name", "Last_Name" and "User_Name". I am not 100% sure, but maybe the also contain a space character, near the `_`. If so, please rename your column names, exclude the space characters. Then you can use `$r->First_Name`, `$r->Last_Name` and `$r->User_Name` in your code.